# Push notifications vs Local notifications vs phone calls vs Do not disturb

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, localnotification

Is there any way for my app to detect if I got a push notification vs a local notification vs a phone call vs do not disturb phone call (the phone call is just silent when do not disturb is on).

Is there any method the app calls depending on which notification/phone call occurs.

So i know so far `applicatonWillResignActive` will be called when there is an incoming phone call. If the user takes the call `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called, if the user ignores the call `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called

Answer (score 0):

When Push notification will come then below method will call if your app is running

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

When Local notification will come then below method will call if your app is running

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Both above methods you need to implement in appdelegate.m

Comment: what about phone call vs do not disturb

Comment: As you already knew about applicatonWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationDidBecomeActive and according to my knowledge there is no work around for phone calls.